# How to find out if one string is a rotation of another

Tags: c, string

I have two strings `a` and `b`. I want to know if `a` is rotation of `b` or vice versa without creating a third string.

Comment: And what have you tried so far to find this out?

Comment: I first of all compared their lengths if matched i proceded with finding the first alphabet of string a in b and then char by char comparing.

Comment: Then it is a good idea to say this in the question, as it shows that you have actually tried do do something yourself. When you ask a question and the question sounds like you have not tried anything, the question usually gets downvoted and eventually closed. In future, explain the things you have tried yourself and it will increase your chances of getting a good answer.

Comment: Is any algorithm ok, or do you have any special restrictions on run time? O(n²) on length isn't too hard, more or less brute force.

Comment: I want it to be as optimized as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string a is a rotation of b if and only if there is an L such that L == len(a) == len(b), and there is an offset 0 <= j < len(a) such that a[ (i+j) % L] == b[i] for all 0 <= i < L.

In c code (assuming that L is the common length of the strings. Returns 1 if a is a rotation of b, 0 otherwise):

```
int i, j, is_rot;
for (i = 0; i< L; i++){
    is_rot = 1;
    for (j = 0; j<L; j++){
        if (a[ (j + i) %L] != b[j] ){
            is_rot = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (is_rot) return 1;
}
return 0;
```

Comment: for (j = 0; j<L; j++)
        is_rot = 1;

Wont it just execute the statement L times?

Comment: Woops. Edited it up to where it belongs, and added another missing brace. Lesson to self: test the code before posting it :)

Comment: still missing a brace but thanks :)

Comment: I am hopeless. Hope it helped :)